# Disable Azure DevOps feature where #ID in a discussion relates the two work items?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps Boards, if you open a work item and reference another in the discussion field by using #ID for the work item you want to discuss, ADB automatically relates those two items.

More recently, the dev team has determined that the code review tool they are using is tying reviews to multiple work items because of this related field.

Other than telling the team to avoid using the #ID feature or manually removing related work items from each story and task, is there a way to prevent #ID from relating work items, but still allowing the live link in the discussion thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#ID` control quickly links objects to work items. With this control, you can specify or select a work item ID and **it's automatically linked to the object**.

Use the #ID control within the following areas:

- A work item discussion or any rich-text field
- A pull request discussion
- Commit comments
- Changeset or shelveset comments
- Wiki page

> Is there a way to prevent #ID from relating work items, but still
>   allowing the live link in the discussion thread?

Sorry it's not able to do this. This is by designed, it will automatically link to the object in Azure DevOps.

If you really do not want this, you may have to avoid to use #ID or manually remove the link relationship.

More details about link work item you could also kindly refer this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; that was I was afraid of.  We'll have to work out a better process for the team, then.

Answer (score 0):

for Azure DevOps 2019/2020

You could enable or disable commit mention work item resolution , for details you could visit : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops

I've test 2019 and 2020 version , it works fine for me.